# Filtering soft-deleted data with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, filter, fluent-nhibernate, soft-delete

I'm trying to implement simple soft deletes in my application using Fluent NHibernate. All entities have a boolean flag `IsDeleted`, and delete operation only sets this property to true.
I'm struggling with querying more complex entities referencing each other, for example by having many-to-many relationship. Let's say I have `Person` entity, having a collection of `Project`s:

```
class Person : Entity {
    public virtual IList<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

class Project : Entity {
    //some properties
}
```

Now imagine that `Person` p has `Project`s proj1 and proj2. If proj1 gets soft-deleted, we simply set its `IsDeleted` property to true. However, when I access p's projects, collection is automatically lazy-loaded with proj1 too, independently from its flag. Of course, I can always filter the collection, for example by `Projects.Where(x => !x.Isdeleted)`, but this leads to repetitive code prone to bugs. I want to separate this kind of data juggling from my presentation layer.

I want to automatize this process by some global rule saying "load only entities with `IsDeleted` set to false", which applies to all queries and lazy-loaded collections.

What I have tried:

- Override events, but I wasn't able to intercept all DB reads and filter all entities that are read.
- Filters, which I couldn't get to work with lazy-loaded collections.

What would you recommend, what is the easiest way to implement soft deletes without code repetition and easily separable from presentation layer?

Comment: Can you show us the projects mapping as you can filter at the class xml level directly

Comment: Also see here to see how. http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-filters-for-unmapped-columns-in.html

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Rippo, off the top of my head, something like this should work:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
  public bool IsDeleted {get;set;}
}

public class SomeEntity : BaseEntity
{
   ....
 }

public abstract class EntityMap<T>: ClassMap<T> where T:BaseEntity
{
     public EntityMap()
     {
       Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted);
     }
 }

 public class SomeEntityMap: EntityMap<SomeEntity>
 {
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this method before. However, this won't allow me to dynamically switch between showing/hiding soft-deleted data. But in case I won't need such a feature (spec is still in development), this will easily solve my problem.

Unimportant side note: in the last version of Fluent NHibernate I'm using, Where method accepts only SQL where clause, not lambda.

Comment: Update: I've tested it and it works fine in a simple test project, but I can't get it to work in my application. Where method seems to be totally ignored, I can put anything as a string parameter (even random string) and it still works, clause is never added to the SQL query. I'm using automapping (but in a very simple test application, it works with both automapping and manual mapping). I had similar problem with filters, they simply weren't applied. Any idea what may be wrong? What is blocking this feature?